# How to split a street address after the first number?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not sure how to solve this but I need to split a string into 2 parts. Take the string below for example:

```
North Street 57A 1floor
```

I need to split this into 2 parts.
Part 1 "North Street 57" and part 2 "A 1floor"

But if the address is just "North Street 57" then I don't need to split the string at all, so the key here is to identify if the first occurrence of street number is only digits or a combination of digits and characters (57A)

I have a lot of different address names so the text can vary. Can this be achieved?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What didn't worked?

Comment: What if you have `North Street 1floor?`

Comment: If its "North Street 1floor" then it should be.. part 1 "North Street 1" and part 2 "floor"

Comment: @Sinatr I dont know how to be able to detect if the first occurrence of digit also have a character in it, this is key to be able to split the string at the correct place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want to split after the first occurrence of a number, you may use [Regular Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) for that.

Here's a full example:

```
string input = "North Street 57A 1floor";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\d)(?=\D)");
var parts = regex.Split(input, 2);
foreach (var part in parts)
    Console.WriteLine(part);
```

Output:

```
North Street 57
A 1floor
```

The pattern `(?<=\d)(?=\D)` gets the position *after* a string of digits. Then, we use [`Regex.Split(string input, int count)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Split_System_String_System_Int32_) where `count=2` to ensure that it returns two parts at maximum.

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/TAAFIK80749)**.

Comment: @MTplus I've updated the pattern as the previous one would return two parts for "North Street 57" where the second part is an empty string. This is now fixed. Please use the updated pattern.